# Avoid expansion of macros while using boost preprocessor sequences

Tags: c++, boost, preprocessor, boost-preprocessor

I'm trying to get the OS and compiler name as a string in C++. Although there are many questions about this I did not find a definitive answer. So I tried to use Boost.Predef 1.55 which defines macros of the type `BOOST_OS_<OS>` and `BOOST_OS_<OS>_NAME`.

Hence one could simply do `if(BOOST_OS_<OS>) return BOOST_OS_<OS>_NAME;` for every OS boost supports. Same for compilers with `COMP` instead of `OS`. To avoid the repetition I wanted to use Boost.Preprocessor and put them all in a loop.

What I came up with is this:

```
#define MAKE_STMT_I2(PREFIX) if(PREFIX) return PREFIX ## _NAME;
#define MAKE_STMT_I(type, curName) MAKE_STMT_I2(BOOST_ ## type ## _ ## curName)
#define MAKE_STMT(s, type, curName) MAKE_STMT_I(type, curName)
#define OS_LIST (AIX)(AMIGAOS)(ANDROID)(BEOS)(BSD)(CYGWIN)(HPUX)(IRIX)(LINUX)(MACOS)(OS400)(QNX)(SOLARIS)(UNIX)(SVR4)(VMS)(WINDOWS)(BSDI)(DRAGONFLY)(BSD_FREE)(BSD_NET)(BSD_OPEN)

    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(MAKE_STMT, OS, OS_LIST)
```

However I run into problems where the values are expanded to soon. E.g. VMS defines already a macro named `VMS` which then gets replaced in `OS_LIST`. Even doing something like `#define OS_LIST (##AIX##)(##AMIGAOS##)(...` does not help as it seems to get expanded in boost later.

How can I avoid the expansion in the sequence completely?

Comment: Include _s in the tokens?

Comment: What do you mean? If I do `VMS_s` I won't be able to get to the boost macro from that

Comment: Move the `_` from  `## _ ##` in `MAKE_STMT_I` to `_CYGWIN` or what have you.

Comment: Most of the OS Macros are defined this way. So this would make it worse. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/predef/doc/html/predef/reference/boost_os_operating_system_macros.html

Comment: `(##AIX##)` is also illegal, because `(AIX)` is not a single preprocessor token.

Answer (score 2):

Since you rely on the token `VMS` being undefined, a quick solution is a simple `#undef VMS`. Obviously, to avoid breaking code which relies on that macro, you should put your Boost PP code in its own .cpp file.

Comment: Yeah, was thinking about that too. Would be a lot of undefs though.

Comment: Whenever you get clever with the preprocessor, you are asking for trouble down the line. Is there a way to use a macro name which isn't being used elsewhere?

Comment: I need to get to e.g. `BOOST_OS_VMS` and `BOOST_OS_VMS_NAME` and want to avoid repetition. So possibly the only variant I could use is `OS_VMS` (prefix all with `OS_` which should not be defined before) at the price of a bit repetition.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I avoid the expansion in the sequence completely?

You can't.  Passing high level data structures as an argument to a macro necessarily involves evaluating the data structure.

You could avoid this problem and still use the boost macros in basically three ways:

### 1. Undefine problem macros before the call

This is essentially what MSalters recommended.

The idea being that if `VMS` isn't defined, its evaluation won't expand it.

Here, you risk `VMS` being left undefined, which could have dire consequences, so you have to mitigate that (MSalters touched on this).

### 2. Build high level macros from different data

2 might for example use:

```
#define OS_LIST (S_AIX)(S_BEOS)(S_VMS)
```

...and require you to change your `MAKE_STMT` macro complex; for example, this:

```
#define MAKE_STMT_I2(PREFIX) if(PREFIX) return PREFIX ## _NAME;
#define MAKE_STMT_I(curName) MAKE_STMT_I2(BOOST_O ## curName)
#define MAKE_STMT(s, type, curName) MAKE_STMT_I(curName)
#define OS_LIST (S_AIX)(S_AMIGAOS)(S_ANDROID)(S_BEOS)(S_BSD)(S_CYGWIN)(S_HPUX)(S_IRIX)(S_LINUX)(S_MACOS)(S_OS400)(S_QNX)(S_SOLARIS)(S_UNIX)(S_SVR4)(S_VMS)(S_WINDOWS)(S_BSDI)(S_DRAGONFLY)(S_BSD_FREE)(S_BSD_NET)(S_BSD_OPEN)
```

(Note: Here I'm ignoring the type; it's not necessary to pass `OS` in as data to the iteration sequence anyway).

The idea here is to find a different shared portion of `BOOST_OS_FOO` and `BOOST_OS_FOO_NAME` to put in your data, so that your data doesn't include the macros you're defining.

Here, you risk `S_FOO` being defined at some higher level messing you up.  You could mitigate this by finding a different piece to use in your data.

### 3. Build wrapper identifiers

This is easiest to define by example:

```
#define OS_LIST (AIX)(BEOS)(8VMS)
#define BOOST_OS_8VMS BOOST_OS_VMS
#define BOOST_OS_8VMS_NAME BOOST_OS_VMS_NAME
```

The idea here is that you're building *different* `BOOST_OS_xxx` / `BOOST_OS_xxx_NAME` form macros, then remapping those back to the desired ones.  Using a numeric prefix has the advantage of becoming immune to expansion (such entities are valid preprocessor tokens (pp-numbers), but they cannot be object-like macros).

Comment: 2 is essentially my idea in a comment to MSalters answer. 3 is unbearable as this won't save me any work at all, but nice to know the number prefix trick.